# Upload limit on Proftpd?

Tags: ftp, proftpd

Is there a way to limit the number of files uploaded per day per user using proftpd? Is there a way to limit the total size of files uploaded in a day per user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you install the `mod_quotatab` extension: [ProFTPD module mod_quotatab](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab.html)
. You can set a quota on the number of bytes and the number of files permitted. Set up a cron-job to update the *tally* once every 24 hours, and voila, you have a daily quota set up, as [explained here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Quotas.html)